# Unrecoverable syntax error while closing route

Tags: javascript, express

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));



app.get('/split/name', (req, res) => {
    var name=req.query.fullName;
    name=name.split(' ');
    var first=name[0];
    var second=name[1];
    res.status(200).json({firstName: first,secondName:second});

});
// end split name

app.get('/calculate/age', (req, res) => {
    var dob = req.query.dob;
    var getAge = (dob) => {
        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(dob);
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;
        }
        return age;
    }
    res.status(200).json({age: getAge(dob)});
});// i get the error here
```

According to question i am getting input as "/split/name?fullName=ritik verma" and i have to split it into First name and last name
and second part is  "/calculate/age?dob=17-04-1999" and i need to calculate age.

So im giving you the actual question maybe that should help

The question:-

Create an Express application that has following routes and runs on port 3000 -

Route 1 - GET  /split/name - which takes fullName as query parameter and gives firstName and
 lastName as output.

Sample input - /split/name?fullName=Aditya Kumar

Output - {

“firstName”:”Aditya”,

```
“lastName”:”Kumar”
```

}

Route 2 - /calculate/age - which takes date of birth in format yyyy-mm-dd and 
return the age of the person.

Sample input - /calculate/age?dob=1992-02-28

Output - {

“age”:27

}

NOTE: You are not required to use app.listen(). This will be handled by the system.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Could it be the format of the date string?

Comment: `17.04.1999` is a non-stadard date format, so your `getAge` produces `NaN`. I guess that cannot be properly serialised and thus you get an error.

Comment: its asking to add  ';' after the closing brace above "return age"

Answer (score 0):

**Code seems to be working, Just you need to add *app.listen* server to listen on specific port **

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));



app.get('/split/name', (req, res) => {
    var name=req.query.fullName;
    name=name.split(' ');
    var first=name[0];
    var second=name[1];
    res.status(200).json({firstName: first,secondName:second});

});
// end split name

app.get('/calculate/age', (req, res) => {
    var dob = req.query.dob;
    var getAge = (dob) => {
        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(dob);
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;
        }
        return age;
    }
    res.status(200).json({age: getAge(dob)});
});// i get the error here

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server listening port 3000")
})
```

Now try any of the following

- http://localhost:3000/calculate/age?dob=11.12.1980
- http://localhost:3000/split/name?fullName=Kishor%20ranga

tested locally 
   [image]

[image]

Comment: ya i too cant find any error with it.Maybe it has something to do with the online compiler.

Comment: I tried it's working locally perfectly fine.  I am using node version 10.15.0. please verify yours.  Tested locally (added screenshot above) it works fine.

Comment: can you please upload the age one too

Comment: Sure Please find the age one as well. Hope this is was helpful.